# Orden de iptables

Tags: iptables

Estoy intentando implementar una política restrictiva usando *iptables* de la siguiente manera:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

El objetivo es dar acceso solamente al servidor web, pero no me está funcionando. Además, alguna ayuda adicional respecto al orden de las reglas es bienvenida.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta traduciondola al lenguaje del sitio. Sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Perdón, creí que estaba en el que está en inglés, ya está traducida.

Answer (score 2):

Hola en primer lugar deberias limpiar las politicas actuales con un flush en las tablas

```
iptables -F # con esto se borran reglas
iptables -X # con esto se borran cadenas
iptables -Z # con esto se ponen esticas a cero
```

luego aplicar las politicas por defectos en este caso destinadas a drop

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP   
iptables -P FORWARD DROP 
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Ahora las reglas que consideres necesarias. para el caso de internet en el equipo bastaria con (agrego el multiport con los otros puertos ya que tambien supongo queireas http y https de lo contrario solo con --dport 80 seria suficiente)

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT-p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,8080 -j ACCEPT
```

si bien esto deberia funcionar estarais dejando tu equipoo expuesto completamente ya que se permiten todas las entradas por lo que en luagr de esto seria conveniente utilizar estados y solamente permitir las conecciones entrantes que esten vinculadas o relacionadas a una que previamente iniciamos desde el equipo, par aeso en lugar de lo anterior utilizariamos

```
     iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,8080 -j ACCEPT
     iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta que el equipo en el el que aplicas es el servidor, lo había entendido como que era un cliente, en este caso las reglas de estado que te comenté no serían válidas ya que la conexión se inicia desde afuera, por lo que si bien se pueden modificar para cumplir no lo veo necesario, simplemente utiliza las reglas anteriores que no involucran estados

Comment: tu respuesta es correcta. yo le agregaría reglas `MASQUERADE`, `forwarding (NAT)`, `DNS` y todo permitido para `lo`